# How to get selected text in MS Word 2010 (C#)?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I want to get selected text from other applications. I tried UI Automation in .NET and it can get selected text in Notepad, Wordpad, MS Word 2013 using ValuePattern and TextPattern. However, it cannot get text from MS Word 2010.

How can I get selected text in MS Word 2010?